# add multiple data in xml file using PHP xmlwriter

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need to add article for each month in `xml` file using PHP `xmlwriter`:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS YEAR, 
                MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS MONTH 
         FROM ".NEWS_ARTICLES." GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH ";
$newsdata = DataAccess::Fetch($sql);

foreach($newsdata AS $news){
    $writer->openURI('./cache/xmls/posts-'.$news['MONTH'].'-'.$news['YEAR'].'.xml');  
    $writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');  
    $writer->setIndent(4);
    $writer->startElement('urlset');
    $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns', $xmlns);
    $writer->startElement('url');   
    $writer->writeElement('loc',$news['title']);  
    $writer->endElement();  
    $writer->endElement(); 
    $writer->endDocument();   
    $writer->flush();
}
```

This worked For me and generate `.xml` file for each month But not add all articles title for each month and I see only `one` title in each  month file!! how do can I add all articles for each month in xml files?

I think my problem is with loop!!!

result: `posts-5-2015.xml`

```
<url>
  <loc>title</loc>
</url>
```

In Really I have 5 articles and need to:

result: `posts-5-2015.xml`

```
<url>
  <loc>title</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>title2</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>title3</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>title4</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>title5</loc>
</url>
```

`print_r($newsdata)` result: NOTE: this is simple Of large DB and only for schema

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 243
            [title] => test2
            [story] => desc2
            [timestamp] => 1442389680
            [update_time] => 1442389522
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [MONTH] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 242
            [title] => test1
            [story] => desc
            [timestamp] => 1421230680
            [update_time] => 1441026399
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [MONTH] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 244
            [title] => test3
            [story] => desc3
            [timestamp] => 1421230680
            [update_time] => 1441026399
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [MONTH] => 5
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 245
            [title] => test4
            [story] => desc4
            [timestamp] => 1421230680
            [update_time] => 1441026399
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [MONTH] => 5
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 246
            [title] => test5
            [story] => desc5
            [timestamp] => 1421230680
            [update_time] => 1441026399
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [MONTH] => 5
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 247
            [title] => test6
            [story] => desc6
            [timestamp] => 1421230680
            [update_time] => 1441026399
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [MONTH] => 5
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 248
            [title] => test7
            [story] => desc7
            [timestamp] => 1421230680
            [update_time] => 1441026399
            [YEAR] => 2015
            [MONTH] => 5
        )
)
```

Comment: your code Sir, showing `group by Month`,,,ofcourse it will show you only 1 title in a month..

Comment: @J.Zend: can u tell me better way?!

Comment: you want to see all title each month right....so delete `month` from `group by` code...

Comment: @J.Zend: i see the same result: one title to each file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS YEAR, 
                MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS MONTH 
         FROM ".NEWS_ARTICLES." GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH ";
```

Most databases other than MySQL would reject this query, because you're grouping on 2 fields whilst selecting many fields.
The `group by year, month` will only display a single (random) row from a month and hide all the others.

The solution is to drop the `group by` clause entirely and rewrite the query like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS YEAR, 
                MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS MONTH 
         FROM ".NEWS_ARTICLES." ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH ASC";
```

**Remark**
It's odd that you don't have a `WHERE` clause. Do you really want to select **all** articles every time?
A better approach would be to limit the number of articles selected in the query by some filter.
It's always faster to filter in the database rather than in php.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your XML with each loop. Consider starting document with root and closing document outside the `foreach` loop:

```
$writer->openURI('./cache/xmls/posts-'.$news['MONTH'].'-'.$news['YEAR'].'.xml');
$writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8'); 
$writer->setIndent(4); 
$writer->startElement('urlset');

foreach ($newsdata as $news){    
  $writer->startElement('url'); 
  $writer->writeElement('loc',$news['title']); 
  $writer->endElement();
}

$writer->endElement(); 
$writer->endDocument(); 
$writer->flush();
```